# Is there any way to define the Pauli matrices eigenstates symbolically in Mathematica?

Tags: symbolic, custom-notation

I've been trying to define the kets $|+\rangle$ and $|-\rangle$ with no sucess with

```
<< Notation`
Symbolize[ParsedBoxWrapper[Subscript["_", "_"]]]
Subscript[Ket[+], Q] := {1/Sqrt[2], 1/Sqrt[2]}
```

I believe that the error probably occurs because Mathematica tries to interpret the symbol + as an operation, as expected. Is there any workaround to this? P.S: I just added the Q in the subscript for aesthetic reasons, to regard it as a qubit-state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out. This can be solved quite simply if we use the notation package to define

[image]

instead of Symbolize. By doing this we can use the plus sign as a symbol inside the ket.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can specify plus as a string instead, like this:

```
<< Notation`
Symbolize[ParsedBoxWrapper[Subscript["_", "_"]]]
Subscript[Ket["+"], Q] := {1/Sqrt[2], 1/Sqrt[2]}

Subscript[Ket["+"], Q]
(* {1/Sqrt[2], 1/Sqrt[2]} *)
```